# convert rows into columns according to the date that they have in common in R

Tags: r

my data frame **df** is the following:

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           Column1 = c("Station Name:","Date",
                       "01/01/2000","02/01/2000","07/03/2010","31/12/2020",
                       "Station Name:","Date","01/01/2000","02/01/2000",
                       "07/03/2010","31/12/2020","Station Name:","Date","01/01/1999",
                       "02/01/1999","01/10/2009","31/12/2020"),
           Column2 = c("A","Value","2.9","2.42",
                       "2.06","1.92","B","Value","1.19","1.16","1.13",
                       "1.08","C","Value","12.5","8.39","6.48","9.87")
) -> df
```

[image]

And I must transform the rows for them to look like this:

[image]

Comment: perhaps it is better to go to the system outputted this (untidy) data.frame, and prevent it from stitching everything together.. is that a possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option in `tidyverse` where we create a grouping column based on the presence of 'Station Name:' string in 'Column1', create a new column by extracting the `first` value of 'Column2' ('A', 'B', 'C'), then remove the first two rows as they are headers (`slice`), `rename` the column, and reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`.  If needed, `arrange` the rows based on the 'Date' in ascending order

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Column1, 'Station Name:'))) %>% 
  mutate(nm1 = first(Column2)) %>%
  slice(-(1:2)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  rename(Date = Column1) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-grp) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = nm1, values_from = Column2) %>%       
  arrange(dmy(Date))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#  Date           A     B     C
#  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 01/01/1999 NA    NA    12.5 
#2 02/01/1999 NA    NA     8.39
#3 01/01/2000  2.9   1.19 NA   
#4 02/01/2000  2.42  1.16 NA   
#5 01/10/2009 NA    NA     6.48
#6 07/03/2010  2.06  1.13 NA   
#7 31/12/2020  1.92  1.08  9.87
```

---

Or in `base R` with `split/Reduce/merge`

```
out <- type.convert(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'Date', all = TRUE), 
   lapply(split(df, cumsum(grepl('Station Name:', df$Column1))), 
       function(x) setNames(x, c("Date", x$Column2[1]))[-(1:2),])),
       as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option based in the tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(group = LETTERS[cumsum(Column2 %in% LETTERS)]) %>%
  filter(str_detect(Column1, '\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = Column2) %>%
  rename(Date = Column1)

# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#   Date       A     B     C    
#   <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 01/01/2000 2.9   1.19  NA   
# 2 02/01/2000 2.42  1.16  NA   
# 3 07/03/2010 2.06  1.13  NA   
# 4 31/12/2020 1.92  1.08  9.87 
# 5 01/01/1999 NA    NA    12.5 
# 6 02/01/1999 NA    NA    8.39 
# 7 01/10/2009 NA    NA    6.48
```